How can I display an error when I use Spring Security?
I'm building an API using Spring Boot, and I've implemented Spring Security for login and registration. However, when I access an endpoint of my API without a good body, I consistently receive a 403 error. I've tried creating custom error handling, but I'm not sure I handle exceptions for all possible errors.
How can I troubleshoot and identify the specific cause of the 403 error?
What are the common reasons for a 403 error in Spring Security? Are there any best practices or additional configurations I should consider to handle errors effectively?
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                    req.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**","/images/**","static/**")
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest()
                            .authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)            
            .logout(logout ->
                    logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                            .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                            .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext())
            );

    return http.build();
}

that is my configuration i don't know if i do bad things
server.error.include-message=always
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG

why are you not using the built in JWT features of spring security? and building some kindof filter for something that already exists in the docs? there is chapter named JWT, look into it

set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG. Then you will be able to see in the logs the error causing 403
